# How to talk about a delay

Tags: synonyms

Could you provide synonyms of "lags behind" as used in this example sentence?

> The chemical reaction **lags behind** the application of heat.

I am seeking idioms to say that chemical reactions take place with a lag some time (say a few seconds) after heat is applied to a tube with reactants.

Comment: What is the source of the example sentence?  Did you write it yourself?

Comment: Yes, it's an example of mine, maybe wrong.

Comment: Lags behind isn't right here.  Perhaps try "The chemical reaction begins shortly after the application of heat."   This isn't an idiom however. Just plain English.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really mean "lags behind".  That means "fails to keep pace with", for example in a race.

In simple formal English, you probably mean, "The chemical reactions start a few seconds after the application of heat."

That's not an idiom, it is just stating the facts in simple words.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer not to mention the seconds. Could I say "lags"? Or "comes with a lag after"?

Comment: Why do you want to use that word?  I'd probably understand what you mean, but I assume you are writing in a fairly formal context, and "lags" has implications of "failing to keep up" or "it should start at the the same time but doesn't". It implies a negative judgement. If you don't want to mention seconds just say "a short time" or "a few moments" or "after a short delay" or similar.